# Move Car Horizontal - Python classes

Tags: python, class

I need to create a class for a car that moves on a horizontal line. The constructor must only have one argument and this is where it is throwing me off. I can only have one argument to initialize the initial position of the bug. It should default to a value of 0 and the initial direction should always be one. But i'm not sure i can do this without 2 arguments in the constructor. I also need two mutator methods for moving and turning the car as well as a accessor method that will display the location of the car.

Example: `position 5 direction right: .....>; position 2 direction left: ..<`

```
class Bug:

    def __init__(self, iPosition=0):
        self.position = iPosition

    def move(self):
        pos = self.postion

    def turn(self):
        direction = self.position

    def display(self):
        if direction < 0:
            x = '<'
        elif direction > 0:
            x = '>'
        for i in range(pos):
            y = '.' + y
        return (y,x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code in the display() function should give you the answer. It has the movement being to the left for negative direction. Hence, a negative value in the constructor's parameter could represent movement to the left.

Comment: Yeah, but when i test the function using `Bug(10)` it tells me '<_main_.Bug instance at 0X00000079E67C8>`

Comment: ... yes? It has made the instance you requested, what is the problem?

Comment: It's not actually displaying the .'s and the >'s when i test the function using tester = Bug(10)

Answer (score 0):

This might be more like what you need:

```
class Bug:

    def __init__(self, iPosition=0):
        self.position = iPosition
        self.direction = 1

    def move(self, distance=1):
        self.position += self.direction * distance

    def turn(self):
        self.direction = -self.direction

    def display(self):
        if self.direction < 0:
            x = '<'
        elif self.direction > 0:
            x = '>'
        y = ''
        for i in range(self.position): # this is not right if position is negative; maybe abs()?
            y = '.' + y
        return (y,x)
```

Comment: Just one question: Where is y being defined in the display() function?

Comment: @RobH Good point... this was pretty much a copy-pasta-tweak, and I missed that `y` was not defined. Added an explicit initialization...

Comment: How do I create a bug object at position 10 using another function? Is it simply `Bug(10)`?

Comment: @user3014014 Yes, something like `some_variable = Bug(10)` would create a Bug object and call it's constructor with 10 as the first (non-self) argument. Then `some_variable.turn()` will turn it around, and `some_variable.move()` or `some_variable.move(5)` (or any other value) will move it.

Comment: the only problem i'm facing now is that it won't display the .'s and >'s. Is there something i'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: What happens if you do e.g. `x = Bug(10); x.move(5); x.display()`? It worked for me... If you're wanting to define a function that automatically displays those values when you just type `x`, `display()` is not the right function that would be `__repr__` instead.

Comment: i've added my new testing function to the bottom. it still doesn't display ...> or anything like this. What am i doing wrong?